# Codeigniter - Please suggest me that how to add pagination in this search engine

Tags: codeigniter

--

### -- Database: `ci-intro`

CREATE DATABASE `ci-intro` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `ci-intro`;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `posts`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `posts`

INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`, `body`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'Another day Still Looking', 'My Lion ran off', '2013-04-02 08:20:20', '2013-04-03 12:43:49'),
(2, 'A good day', 'The Lion is back in one piece.', '2013-04-02 08:20:44', '2013-04-02 08:20:44'),
(3, 'Thank GOD', 'Everything belongs to my father', '2013-04-02 08:21:03', '2013-04-02 08:21:03'),
(4, 'At the seaside', 'We went down to the sea side, then it started raining!', '2013-04-02 08:21:35', '2013-04-03 19:28:48'),
(5, 'Boring posts', 'The events diary is not interesting', '2013-04-02 08:21:55', '2013-04-03 19:35:25');

---

application\controllers\posts.php

```
function search()
{
    $data['title'] = "Blogging";
    $data['heading'] = "Bloging";

    $this->load->view('view_search', $data);
}
```

application\views\view_search.php

```
    <?php echo form_fieldset('<b>Search a Post!</b>');?>

    <?php echo form_open('posts/execute_search'); ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="border:dashed"  bgcolor="#FFCC99">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <?php echo form_label('Search: enter keyword, title, content '); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <?php  echo form_input(array('name'=>'search')); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top"><?php echo nbs(1); ?></td>
            <td valign="top" class="style1"><?php echo form_submit('search_submit','Submit'); ?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php echo form_fieldset_close(); ?>
```

application\controllers\posts.php

```
public function execute_search($search_term)
{
    $data['title'] = "Blogging";
    $data['heading'] = "Bloging";


    $search_term = $_POST['search'];

    $rs = $this->db->like('title', trim($search_term))
            ->or_like('body', trim($search_term))
            ->get('posts');
    $total = $rs->num_rows();

    $data['results'] = $rs->result();

    $this->load->view("view_index", $data); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use pagination.. you need to use pagination class library of codeigniter ...  load the library

```
 $this->load->library('pagination');
```

and call function in your controller

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
 $config['total_rows'] = 200;
 $config['per_page'] = 20; 

 $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

and print create_lnks where you want your pagination to stay...(view)..

```
  echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

you can go through the docs [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)... to read more about the pagination class.. and about customization

Comment: And a tip, if you need pagination in 70% of your web app, add the pagination to /application/config/autoload.php and move the pagination configuration to your configuration file.